# Restart multiple Docker containers using Ansible

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, ansible-inventory

how do i dynamically restart all my docker containers from Ansible? I mean i know a way where i can define my containers in a variable and loop through them but what i want to achieve is this -

Fetch the currently running containers and restart all or some of them one by one through some loop.

How to achieve this using Ansible?

Answer (score 4):

#### Docker explanation

Retrieve name/image for all the running container:

```
docker container ls -a --format '{{.Names}} {{.Image}}'
```

You could also filter the output of the `docket container` command to a specific image name, thanks to the `--filter ancestor=image_name` option:

```
docker container ls -a --filter ancestor=alpine --format '{{.Names}} {{.Image}}'
```

#### Ansible integration:

First I would define some filters as Ansible variables:

```
  vars:
    - image_v1: '--filter ancestor=my_image:v1'
    - image_v2: '--filter ancestor=my_image:v2'
```

Them I will execute the `docker container` command in a dedicated task and save the command output to an Ansible variable:

```
 - name: Get images name
   command: docker container ls -a {{ image_v1 }} {{ image_v2 }} --format "{{ '{{' }}.Names {{ '}}' }} {{ '{{' }}.Image {{ '}}' }}"
   register: docker_images
```

Finally I will iterate over it and use it into the `docker_container` ansible module:

```
- name: Restart images
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.split(' ')[0]}}"
    image: "{{ item.split(' ')[1]}}"
    state: started
    restart: yes
  loop: "{{ docker_images.stdout_lines}}"
```

**final playbook.yml**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - image_v1: '--filter ancestor=my_image:v1'
    - image_v2: '--filter ancestor=my_image:v2'
  tasks:
    - name: Get images name
      command: docker container ls -a {{ image_v1 }} {{ image_v2 }} --format "{{ '{{' }}.Names {{ '}}' }} {{ '{{' }}.Image {{ '}}' }}"
      register: docker_images

    - name: Restart images
      docker_container:
        name: "{{ item.split(' ')[0]}}"
        image: "{{ item.split(' ')[1]}}"
        state: started
        restart: yes
      loop: "{{ docker_images.stdout_lines}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But this will retrieve all the images. What if i want to restart containers of any particular image? How do i achieve it

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that point in your question ^^' You could add a filter based on image name to the docker command `--filter "name={{ your_variable }}" `

Comment: You also could apply a filter based on docker image: `--filter "ancestor=alpine"`

Comment: @SolaVall -That's Brilliant. Thanks for the detailed response. I have also tried to work using the below but it keeps failing in the loop. May be I am not iterating properly over the loop. Can you guide?

```---
- name: restart app servers
  hosts: shashank-VM
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Get info on the Container
      shell: docker ps | awk '/{{ item }}/{print $1}'
      register: list_of_containers
      with_items:
        - ubuntu
 
   - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ list_of_containers.results.stdout_lines }}"```

Comment: Its failing with this error -
** fatal: [shashank-VM]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'"} **

And my variable does contain the list -

``` "stdout_lines": [
                    "466236fa1676", 
                    "74d1c2d3effb"
                ]```